# How to setup PHP Server for Flex app

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I am creating a Flex project on my Windows machine but it will deploy on my Linux machine.

For application server type I selected `PHP`

I click next to go to the next screen.

I am then asked for Web root. I put in `/var/www` which is the web root of the linux server where the application will be.

I get an error telling me:

> The selected web root folder does not exist.

Of course it does not exist on my windows machine, its on my linux machine. It will not let me click finish.

What do I do? do I have to author my Flex app on the same machine that it will be deployed? I hope not since I do not have a Linux version of Flash Builder.

**edit:**
By the way I am following this [tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/testdrive/articles/1_build_a_flex_app.html) if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the web root on your windows machine.  Sounds like Flex wants to know the webroot so it knows where the testing server is.  If you do not have a webroot on your windows machine just install [Wampserver](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/) or [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)

You can get away without installing a wamp server. just make sure the Web Root is a folder that acutally exists. then you can ftp the files over the linux machine for testing.  Its easier to have the server on the same machine but whatever your preference is.

Comment: My windows machine is not a web server. So you are saying I do have to author on the same machine that I deploy on, in order to do this?

Comment: you will most likely need a wamp (windows apache mysql php) server insalled for testing

Comment: you can get away without installing a wamp server.  just make sure the Web Root is a folder that acutally exists.  then you can ftp the files over the linux machine for testing